# 2D fighting game AI, trained to mimic the player's playstyle?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I don't want the AI to be able to beat the player, I want the AI to analyze the player's playstyle, and mimic it.

My current plan is to track every action the player makes, and put it in a group depending on the situation. So if I fireball at long range a lot, the "long range" group of actions will have mostly fireballs in it; when the AI is at long range it would look at the actions in the "long range" group, then it would end up doing mostly fireballs. When I'm at close range it'd have a different action set.

But doing this requires too many groups of actions. Depending on my state, enemy's state, our distance, who's cornered, our hp difference, etc, each of those situations would be a different group of actions. There's 100s of them.

Is there an alternative approach? Or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

They are not all different groups, but nested groups.

```
distance Far{

    when winning{
          attack{
             moves:
             frequency:
          }
          defense{
             moves:
             frequency:
          }
    }
    when even{
          ///
    }
    when losing{
          ///
    }
}
```

By nesting them wisely you can speed things up and make it relatively easy to keep track of. In the above example if distance is Far, check if winning, losing, or roughly tied, then compare attack vs defense frequency. Based on attack vs defense frequency select attack or defense group. From move group select specific move by frequency.